# Reverse hover effect on posts

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm building a website with WordPress, and the theme I am using has hover on post effect. I would like to reverse it, so the post image would be darker before hover, and full color with mouse on it.

Website: http://fotozakatek.com

I'm not really familiar with CSS, but that's probably the right piece of code:

```
.posts { margin-top: -3.95%; }

.posts .post {
    display: block;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 30.7%;
    margin-top: 3.95%;
    padding-bottom: 30.7%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;

}

.posts .post + .post { margin-left: 3.95%; }
.posts .post:nth-child(3n+1) { margin-left: 0; }

.post-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.archive-post-overlay {
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.sticky .post-overlay > p {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 30px;
    font-size: 0.875em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #999;
}

.sticky .post-overlay > p span {
    margin-right: 9px;
    font-size: 18px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: -1px;
}

.archive-post-header {
    position: absolute;
    right: 30px;
    bottom: 30px;
    left: 30px;
}

.archive-post-title {
    font-size: 1.375em;
    line-height: 120%;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #222;
    word-break: break-word;
    -ms-word-break: break-word;
}

.archive-post-date {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-size: 0.875em;
    color: #999;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.post:hover .post-overlay { opacity: 1; }
.post:hover .archive-post-title { color: #3bc492; }
```

Comment: Link is not working!

Comment: Uhmm, I just it checked on two laptops and my phone, it should be working just fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an overlay that is hidden (`opacity: 0`), then on `:hover`, the overlay shows (`opacity: 1`). You want to reverse those so that the overlay is visible by default, and hidden on hover.

These changes are in style.css

- ~ line 604, in `.post-overlay` remove the `opacity: 0.5`
- ~ line 669, in `.has-post-thumbnail .post-overlay` remove `opacity: 0`
- ~ line 664, in `.post:hover .post-overlay` change `opacity: 1` to `opacity: 0`.